# TypeError: unbound method Trying to run functions from class

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, class

When I try to run my functions `orbitPropandcoordTrans` and `interpolation` from a class `Prop` I created I get an error:

> TypeError: unbound method orbitPropandcoordTrans() must be called with
>   prop instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

This is my first attempt at creating a class and I'm not quite sure where `self` comes into it, and which variables need `self.` in front.

Everything was running fine when they were two separate functions before I created the class.

Full Code:

```
'''
Class with functions to: 
  -Create a sample orbit
  -Propagate the orbit
  -Convert the times from J2000 to UTC
  -Convert the cartesian coordinates to latitude, longitude, and altitude
  -Map a groundtrace
  -Interpolate a 0-4 deg longitude window
  -Save data

The orbit generation and propagation are done with OrbitalPy.

'''



import orbital
from orbital import earth, KeplerianElements, plot
import mpl_toolkits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from astropy import time
from astropy.time import TimeDelta, Time
from astropy import units as u
from astropy import coordinates as coord
from astropy.table import Table
from astropy.io import ascii

class Prop:
    def orbitPropandcoordTrans(self, initial_alt, propNum, orbit_initial_J2000_time, ecc, inc, raan, arg_perig, meanAnom, meanMotion):  #orbitPropandcoordTrans(Number of Propagations [], J2000 Times for original orbit [s], Eccentricity [], Inclination [deg], Right Ascension of the Ascending Node [deg], Argument of Perigee [deg], Mean Anomaly [deg], Mean Motion [revolutions per day]): 
        '''
        Create original orbit and run for 100 propagations (in total one whole orbit)
        in order to get xyz and time for each propagation step.
        The end goal is to plot the lat, lon, & alt data to see if it matches ISS groundtrace.
        '''

        'Calculate Avg. Period from Mean Motion'
        avgPeriod = 86400 / meanMotion


        'Generate Orbit'
        # Period version
        #orbit = KeplerianElements.with_period(avgPeriod, body=earth, e=ecc, i=(np.deg2rad(inc)), raan=(np.deg2rad(raan)), arg_pe=(np.deg2rad(arg_perig)), M0=(np.deg2rad(meanAnom))) #ref_epoch=   

        # Alt version
        orbit = KeplerianElements.with_altitude(initial_alt, body=earth, e=ecc, i=(np.deg2rad(inc)), raan=(np.deg2rad(raan)), arg_pe=(np.deg2rad(arg_perig)), M0=(np.deg2rad(meanAnom))) #ref_epoch=   


        'Propagate Orbit and retrieve xyz'
        x = np.empty(propNum, dtype=float)                    #X Coordinate for propagated orbit step
        y = np.empty(propNum, dtype=float)                    #Y Coordinate for propagated orbit step
        z = np.empty(propNum, dtype=float)                    #Z Coordinate for propagated orbit step
        prop_time_J2000 = np.empty(propNum, dtype=float)      #Time for each propagated orbit step
        #propNum = 100                                        #Number of propagations and Mean Anomaly size (one orbit 2pi/propNum)

        for i in range(propNum):
            orbit.propagate_anomaly_by(M=(2.0*np.pi/propNum)) #Propagate the orbit by the Mean Anomaly
            x[i] = orbit.r.x                                  #x vals
            y[i] = orbit.r.y                                  #y vals
            z[i] = orbit.r.z                                  #z vals
            prop_time_J2000[i] = orbit_initial_J2000_time     #J2000 time vals



        'Getting the correct J2000 Time'
        array_initial_time = [orbit_initial_J2000_time ] * propNum  #setting each element in times equal to the original J2000 time
        orbit_J2000_time = np.empty(propNum, dtype=float)           #J2000 times

        for i in range(propNum):
            orbit_J2000_time[i] = array_initial_time[i] + (avgPeriod/propNum)*i 



        '''Because the prop_time_J2000 is only the time between each step to be the sum of itself plus
        all the previous times. And then I need to convert that time from seconds after J2000 to UTC.'''
        prop_time_utc = []  #UTC times for each propagation list

        for i in range(propNum):
            prop_time_utc.append((Time(2000, format='jyear') + TimeDelta(prop_time_J2000[i]*u.s)).iso)  #Convert time from J2000 to UTC



        '''Now I have xyz and time for each propagation step and need to convert the coordinates from
        ECI to Lat, Lon, & Alt'''
        xyz = np.empty(propNum, dtype=float)      #Xyz coordinates from OrbitalPy initial orbit propagation
        cartrep = np.empty(propNum, dtype=float)  #Cartesian Representation
        gcrs = np.empty(propNum, dtype=float)     #Geocentric Celestial Reference System/Geocentric Equatorial Inertial, the default coord system of OrbitalPy
        itrs = np.empty(propNum, dtype=float)     #International Terrestrial Reference System coordinates
        lat = np.empty(propNum, dtype=float)      #Longitude of the location, for the default ellipsoid
        lon = np.empty(propNum, dtype=float)      #Longitude of the location, for the default ellipsoid
        alt = np.empty(propNum, dtype=float)      #Height of the location, for the default ellipsoid

        for i in range(propNum):
            xyz = (x[i], y[i], z[i])                                                  #Xyz coord for each prop. step
            cartrep = coord.CartesianRepresentation(*xyz, unit=u.m)                   #Add units of [m] to xyz
            gcrs = coord.GCRS(cartrep, obstime=time.Time(prop_time_utc[i]))           #Let AstroPy know xyz is in GCRS
            itrs = gcrs.transform_to(coord.ITRS(obstime=time.Time(prop_time_utc[i]))) #Convert GCRS to ITRS
            loc = coord.EarthLocation(*itrs.cartesian.xyz)                            #Get lat/lon/height from ITRS
            lat[i] = loc.lat.value                                                    #Create latitude array
            lon[i] = loc.lon.value                                                    #Create longitude array
            alt[i] = loc.height.value           



        lat = np.array(lat)
        lon = np.array(lon)
        alt = np.array(alt)
        orbit_J2000_time = np.array(orbit_J2000_time)

        #return orbit_J2000_time, lat, lon, alt, avgPeriod, x, y, z, propNum, orbit_initial_J2000_time , ecc, inc, raan, arg_perig, meanAnom, meanMotion
        return orbit_J2000_time, prop_time_utc, lat, lon, alt, x, y, z, propNum, orbit_initial_J2000_time, ecc, inc, raan, arg_perig, meanAnom, meanMotion, avgPeriod





    def interpolation(self, orbit_J2000_time, lat, lon, alt):
        '''
        INTERPOLATION
        '''


        'Get lat, lon, alt, and time vals in a 10 degree window'

        points_in_window = np.where(np.abs(lon-2)<15) #finds the times for the values of longitude that are in a 10 deg window centered around the 0-3 deg window
        time_in_10deg_window = orbit_J2000_time[points_in_window]           #change from 2D array to 1D array
        #print 'time_in_10deg_window', time_in_10deg_window

        lon_in_10deg_window = lon[points_in_window]            #find the longitude vals in the 10 deg window
        lat_in_10deg_window = lat[points_in_window]            #find the latitude vals in the 10 deg window
        alt_in_10deg_window = alt[points_in_window]            #find the altitude vals in the 10 deg window
        #print ''
        #print 'time_in_10deg_window', time_in_10deg_window
        #print ''
        ##prop_time_utc = 



        'Find fit coefficients for 10 deg window'
        polynom_deg =  3 #polynomial degree of fit

        fit_lon = np.polyfit(time_in_10deg_window, lon_in_10deg_window, polynom_deg)  #get fit coefficients for longitude in the 10 deg window
        fit_lat = np.polyfit(time_in_10deg_window, lat_in_10deg_window, polynom_deg)  #get fit coefficients for latitude in the 10 deg window
        fit_alt = np.polyfit(time_in_10deg_window, alt_in_10deg_window, polynom_deg)  #get fit coefficients for altitude in the 10 deg window
        #print 'fit_lon', fit_lon



        'Find start and stop times of 0-4 deg window'
        fit_time = np.polyfit(lon_in_10deg_window, time_in_10deg_window, polynom_deg)  #get fit coefficients for TIME in the 10 deg window
        #print 'fit_time', fit_time
        #print ''
        time_start = np.polyval(fit_time, 0)  #start time for 0-4 deg window
        time_stop = np.polyval(fit_time, 4)   #stop time for 0-4 deg window



        'Generate Spacecraft time in 0-4 deg window '
        #spacecraft time in 0-4 deg window
        time_04_window = np.arange(time_start, time_stop, 1)  #generate 1 second cadence times within the 0-4 deg window
        #print 'time_04_window', time_04_window
        #print ''



        'Interpolate for 0-4 deg window'
        lon_04_window = np.polyval(fit_lon, time_04_window)  #interpolated longitude vals for 0-4 deg window
        lat_04_window = np.polyval(fit_lat, time_04_window)  #interpolated latitude vals for 0-4 deg window
        alt_04_window = np.polyval(fit_alt, time_04_window)  #interpolated altitude vals for 0-4 deg window

        return time_04_window, lon_04_window, lat_04_window, alt_04_window





'Run Functions'


orbit_J2000_time, prop_time_utc, lat, lon, alt, x, y, z, propNum, orbit_initial_J2000_time, ecc, inc, raan, arg_perig, meanAnom, meanMotion, avgPeriod = Prop.orbitPropandcoordTrans((400*1000), 100, 20027712.00, 0, 0, 172.5018, 323.1066, 173.4358, 15.68522506)

time_04_window, lon_04_window, lat_04_window, alt_04_window = Prop.interpolation(orbit_J2000_time, lat, lon, alt)
```

Comment: `orbit_J2000_time, prop_time_utc, lat, lon, alt, x, y, z, propNum, orbit_initial_J2000_time, ecc, inc, raan, arg_perig, meanAnom, meanMotion, avgPeriod = Prop.orbitPropandcoordTrans((400*1000), 100, 20027712.00, 0, 0, 172.5018, 323.1066, 173.4358, 15.68522506)`. `Prop` is a **class**, and `orbitPropandcoordTrans` isn't a **class/static method**, so it must be called on a `Prop` **instance** (`Prop()`). So, use `Prop().orbitPropandcoordTrans` instead `Prop.orbitPropandcoordTrans` in the above line.

Comment: You're getting that message because you haven't created an instance of your `Prop` class, but are instead calling the method on the class itself. It seems as though you are using `Prop` as a container for functions rather than using it to bind data and functionality together as in object-oriented programming. In this case, I would eliminate the class entirely.

Comment: @kindall Make an answer and explain why